# gradle.properties fail reading property with dot notation

Tags: gradle, properties

I receive an error reading a property with dot notation from `gradle.properties`. Why?

If I use `version` instead of `build.version` everything is OK.
Thanks in advance.

## FAIL CASE

**gradle.properties**

```
build.version=2.0.1
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'java'

task testProperties << {
    println "***************** TEST **********************"
    println build.version
    println "*********************************************"
}
```

#### EXECUTION

```
... $ gradle devTest
:devTest
***************** TEST **********************
:devTest FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '..../build.gradle' line: 50

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':devTest'.
> Could not find property 'version' on task ':build'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or<br> --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

## SUCCES CASE

**gradle.properties**

```
version=2.0.1
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'java'

task testProperties << {
    println "***************** TEST **********************"
    println version
    println "*********************************************"
}
```

#### EXECUTION

```
... $ gradle devTest

:devTest

***************** TEST **********************
2.0.1

*********************************************

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You cannot use properties with a dot in this way because Groovy thinks it's a `version` property of the `build` instance. If you want a property to contain a dot then you should use it in the following way:

```
println rootProject.properties['build.version']
```

Answer (score 17):

Another way to get access to the properties is using syntax below

```
println "Version: ${project.'build.version'}"
```

Comment: or  println "Version: ${project['build.version']}"

Answer (score 2):

And another one:

```
println property('build.version')
println "Version: ${property('build.version')}"
```

or

```
println ext['build.version']
println "Version: ${ext['build.version']}"
```

See [Properties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#N15078) and [Extra Properties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#N150E3) documentation.